French Characters not being correctly represented in Delphi 2007
I have a Delphi 2007 application. We recently discovered that a few French accented characters do not display correctly:

Œ : Displays as a ? or a boldened |
œ : Displays as a ? or a boldened |
Ÿ : Displays as a ? or a boldened |

I tried this in Delphi 10.2 and I am able to input these characters correctly. I am wondering if this is a limitation to Delphi 2007?
I tried changing the edit properties of OEMConvert to true, but it converts all French characters to their English equivalencies.

See if Handling a Unicode String in Delphi Versions <= 2007 helps.

The ability to use Œ in a non-unicode delphi also depends on your system locale. I have tested here on a Windows 1252 (Western Europe), using Delphi 6. It works just fine.  Info on Œ here. Notice though that there can sometimes be a difference between typing the character and pasting the character, since Windows may convert to UTF8 when pasting.

Is the problem that you can't INPUT the characters correctly, or that you can't DISPLAY the characters correctly, or both? These are two separate issues, but you mention both in different contexts (display in 2007, input in 10.2). Please [edit] your question to clarify, preferably with a real example/[mcve]

Either upgrade to a Unicode aware Delphi (the best option) or use TntUnicode components (a viable option as a last resort, but not recommended at all)

Does the font that you are using in your application support of showing these characters?

@SilverWarior the issue was the font in question didn't support those specific french characters. Appreciate the assistance!

@ramsaytk People often forget to check font capability especially those that come from English speaking countries since they don't have to deal with special character in their daily lives. But those of us who come from non-English speaking countries do know the hassle of needing and not always having language specific special characters.

The issue was resolved by updating the font to a font that accepts those types of french characters, bit a of a strange one.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
